# Problem in connecting to Atmel Corp. AVR ISP mkII and FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC

Tags: usb

I am using ubuntu 16.04 for programming purposes. When  I am trying to connect to my "Atmel Corp. AVR ISP mkII microcontroller" & "FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC" through my controller software application it doesn't get connected and gives out an error that "inappropriate permissions on device!".

When I plug in the device, it is seen as /dev/ttyUSB0 being an FTDI chip.

Any Idea on how to make the device get connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your user to the appropriate group - *dialout* with the command below:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```

then logout and login back.

Comment: Through the stated method, I am now able to access the atmel microcontroller in serial mode through /dev/ttyUSB0 in the controller software.              But I am not able to access the FTDI chip. In the FTDI mode in controller software it still says that "inappropriate permissions on device!". Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I do not have such programmer and software, but I think that there is some problem with permissions. Normal user can't do `modprobe` and so on. I found [possible solution on Unix StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216630/57134). I can't try it.